# Download a PNG from URL LookIntoBitcoin

Tags: image, url, download, png, bitcoin

There is a page with URL:
https://www.lookintobitcoin.com/charts/1-year-hodl-wave/

I'm designing a page and I just want to reference the "image" of this URL.
It has a download PNG file, how can i just get the path/url to this png image file?

Here is the image icon, but i cant figure out how to get the url path to just the png file.
Can anyone show me how to get it?

[image]

Comment: It's dynamically generated, simplest to just use Selenium

Comment: Yep, as Martheen said It's dynamically generated →`at client side`←. Selenium or PhantomJS (https://phantomjs.org/) should solve your problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This image is dynamically generated at client side (browser), so here is two ways to solve your problem:

1. Use [Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)) or [PhantomJS](https://phantomjs.org/) (both using headless browser technology) to emulate browser behaviour and automatically "press" download button at background.
2. Fetch JSON data and create graph by yourself (for example [how to create PNG image based on txt file in python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-create-graph-from-text-file/))

I recommend second way because it more flexible and you will be able to widely customize result image. But it may be more complicated than headless browser way.

If you want to use second way, you can fetch JSON data using python (for example):

```py
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.lookintobitcoin.com/django_plotly_dash/app/hodl_wave/_dash-update-component'
request_data = {
  "output":"chart.figure",
  "changedPropIds":["url.pathname"],
  "inputs":[
    {
      "id":"url",
      "property":"pathname",
      "value":"/charts/1-year-hodl-wave/"
    }
  ]
}

response = requests.post(url, json=request_data)

print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2))
```

And output will be:

```json
{
  "response": {
    "props": {
      "figure": {
        "data": [
          {
            "line": {
              "color": "#003366",
              "width": 1.2
            },
            "name": "BTC Price",
            "x": [
              "2010-08-17",
              "2020-09-13",
              "2020-09-14",
              ...
              "2021-09-07",
              "2021-09-08"
            ],
            "y": [
              0.07,
              0.07,
              ...
              46215.0
            ],
            "yaxis": "y2",
            "type": "scatter"
          },
          {
            "connectgaps": true,
            "line": {
              "color": "#ffa500",
              "width": 0.8
            },
            "name": "1Yr+ HODL Wave",
            "x": [
              "2010-08-17",
              ...
              "2021-12-16T00:00:00",
              "2021-12-17T00:00:00"
            ],
            "y": [
              0.28032062150000003,
              0.2807032645,
              ...
              0.5101534705064048,
              0.5090896880670537
            ],
            "yaxis": "y",
            "type": "scatter"
          },
          {
            "hoverinfo": "skip",
            "marker": {
              "color": "rgba(255, 207, 209, 0.75)",
              "size": 15
            },
            "mode": "markers",
            "name": "Price Peak",
            "showlegend": true,
            "x": [
              "2011-06-13"
            ],
            "y": [
              20.11
            ],
            "yaxis": "y2",
            "type": "scatter"
          },
          {
            "hoverinfo": "skip",
            "marker": {
              "color": "rgba(255, 207, 209, 0.75)",
              "size": 15
            },
            "mode": "markers",
            "name": "Price Peak",
            "showlegend": false,
            "x": [
              "2011-06-13"
            ],
            "y": [
              0.2979442568
            ],
            "yaxis": "y",
            "type": "scatter"
          },
          {
            "hoverinfo": "skip",
            "marker": {
              "color": "rgba(255, 207, 209, 0.75)",
              "size": 15
            },
            "mode": "markers",
            "name": "Price Peak",
            "showlegend": false,
            "x": [
              "2013-12-02"
            ],
            "y": [
              1047.9
            ],
            "yaxis": "y2",
            "type": "scatter"
          },
          {
            "hoverinfo": "skip",
            "marker": {
              "color": "rgba(255, 207, 209, 0.75)",
              "size": 15
            },
            "mode": "markers",
            "name": "Price Peak",
            "showlegend": false,
            "x": [
              "2013-12-02"
            ],
            "y": [
              0.3877138953
            ],
            "yaxis": "y",
            "type": "scatter"
          },
          {
            "hoverinfo": "skip",
            "marker": {
              "color": "rgba(255, 207, 209, 0.75)",
              "size": 15
            },
            "mode": "markers",
            "name": "Price Peak",
            "showlegend": false,
            "x": [
              "2017-12-20"
            ],
            "y": [
              16811.3
            ],
            "yaxis": "y2",
            "type": "scatter"
          },
          {
            "hoverinfo": "skip",
            "marker": {
              "color": "rgba(255, 207, 209, 0.75)",
              "size": 15
            },
            "mode": "markers",
            "name": "Price Peak",
            "showlegend": false,
            "x": [
              "2017-12-20"
            ],
            "y": [
              0.43133634880000005
            ],
            "yaxis": "y",
            "type": "scatter"
          },
          {
            "hoverinfo": "skip",
            "marker": {
              "color": "rgba(211, 245, 231, 0.75)",
              "size": 15
            },
            "mode": "markers",
            "name": "Price Bottom",
            "showlegend": false,
            "x": [
              "2011-11-22"
            ],
            "y": [
              2.31
            ],
            "yaxis": "y2",
            "type": "scatter"
          },
          {
            "hoverinfo": "skip",
            "marker": {
              "color": "rgba(211, 245, 231, 0.75)",
              "size": 15
            },
            "mode": "markers",
            "name": "Price Bottom",
            "showlegend": false,
            "x": [
              "2011-11-22"
            ],
            "y": [
              0.3073864328
            ],
            "yaxis": "y",
            "type": "scatter"
          },
          {
            "hoverinfo": "skip",
            "marker": {
              "color": "rgba(211, 245, 231, 0.75)",
              "size": 15
            },
            "mode": "markers",
            "name": "Price Bottom",
            "showlegend": false,
            "x": [
              "2015-01-17"
            ],
            "y": [
              201.75
            ],
            "yaxis": "y2",
            "type": "scatter"
          },
          {
            "hoverinfo": "skip",
            "marker": {
              "color": "rgba(211, 245, 231, 0.75)",
              "size": 15
            },
            "mode": "markers",
            "name": "Price Bottom",
            "showlegend": false,
            "x": [
              "2015-01-17"
            ],
            "y": [
              0.5363931366
            ],
            "yaxis": "y",
            "type": "scatter"
          },
          {
            "hoverinfo": "skip",
            "marker": {
              "color": "rgba(211, 245, 231, 0.75)",
              "size": 15
            },
            "mode": "markers",
            "name": "Price Bottom",
            "showlegend": true,
            "x": [
              "2018-12-20"
            ],
            "y": [
              3983.01
            ],
            "yaxis": "y2",
            "type": "scatter"
          },
          {
            "hoverinfo": "skip",
            "marker": {
              "color": "rgba(211, 245, 231, 0.75)",
              "size": 15
            },
            "mode": "markers",
            "name": "Price Bottom",
            "showlegend": false,
            "x": [
              "2018-12-20"
            ],
            "y": [
              0.5097358173
            ],
            "yaxis": "y",
            "type": "scatter"
          }
        ],
        "layout": {
          "hovermode": "closest",
          "images": [
            {
              "layer": "below",
              "opacity": 0.1,
              "sizex": 0.4,
              "sizey": 0.4,
              "source": "https://www.lookintobitcoin.com/static/img/logo/logo-stacked.png",
              "x": 0.4,
              "xref": "paper",
              "y": 0.75,
              "yref": "paper"
            }
          ],
          "legend": {
            "font": {
              "color": "#696969"
            },
            "orientation": "h",
            "x": 0.1
          },
          "margin": {
            "t": 10
          },
          "uirevision": "False",
          "xaxis": {
            "color": "#696969",
            "gridcolor": "#d3d3d3",
            "hoverformat": "%d-%b-%y",
            "range": [
              "2010-08-17",
              "2021-12-17T00:00:00"
            ],
            "showline": true,
            "showspikes": true,
            "spikecolor": "#696969",
            "spikedash": "solid",
            "spikemode": "toaxis+across",
            "spikethickness": 1
          },
          "yaxis": {
            "color": "#696969",
            "hoverformat": "%",
            "range": [
              0,
              1
            ],
            "showgrid": false,
            "showspikes": true,
            ...
            "spikethickness": 1,
            "tickformat": "%",
            "title": {
              "text": "1Yr+ HODL Wave"
            }
          },
          "yaxis2": {
            "color": "#696969",
            "dtick": 1,
            ...
            "spikethickness": 1,
            "ticktext": [
              "$0.001",
              ...
              "$10,000",
              "$100,000"
            ],
            "tickvals": [
              0.001,
              ...
              100000
            ],
            "title": {
              "text": "BTC Price (USD)"
            },
            "type": "log",
            "zeroline": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like i have no other choice. But dang, so much effort just to get an image file. I might just have to put this on hold. thanks for help tho.